# How to create an instance of a class in another class

Tags: php, oop, class

I might be missing something here, I'm not sure. A Google search didn't really help either.

What I'm wanting to do is call the databaseServer class and use its methods within my userControl class. Here is my lib_class.php file:

```
<?php

include('definitions.php');

class databaseServer {

    var $con;
    var $db;
    var $close;
    var $qry;
    var $sql;

    function connect($host,$user,$pw,$db) {
        $this->con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw);
        if (!$this->con) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
        else {
            echo "Database Connected";
            }
        $this->selectDb($db);
        }

    function selectDb($database) {
        $this->db = mysql_select_db($database,$this->con);
        if (!$this->db) {
            echo "Could not Select database";
            }
        else {
            echo "Database Selected";
            }
        }

    function disconnect() {
        $this->close = mysql_close($this->con);
        if ($this->close) {
            echo "Disconnected";
            }
        }

    function query($test) {
        if (!mysql_query($test)) {
            die("Error: " . mysql_error());
            }
        }

} // databaseServer

class cookie {

    var $expireTime;

    function set($name,$value,$expiry) {
        $this->expireTime = time()+60*60*24*$expiry;
        setcookie($name,$value,$expireTime);
        }

    function delete($name) {
        setcookie($name,"",time()-3600);
        }

    function check($name) {
        if (isset($_COOKIE["$name"]))
            echo "Cookie Set";
        else
            echo "Cookie failed";
        }

} //cookie

class userControl {

    public function __construct(databaseServer $server) {
        $this->server = new databaseServer();
    }

    function createUser($uname,$pword) {

        $this->server->connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
        $result = $this->server->query("SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE uname='" . $this->server->real_escape_string($uname) . "'");
        if ($this->result->num_rows() === 0) {

            if ($this->server->query("INSERT INTO user_list (uname, pword) 
            VALUES ('" . $this->server->real_escape_string($uname) . "','" . $this->server->real_escape_string($pword) . "')") {
                echo "User Added Successfully!";
            }
            else {
                echo "Error Adding User!";
            }
        }

        else {
            echo "User Already Exists!";
        }

    } // createUser

} // userControl

?>
```

However, this isn't working and I can't see why. My databaseServer and cookie classes work fine when I omit the userControl class from the file, so I know the error must be in that class somewhere. OOP is something I'm trying to learn and I keep stumbling.

The echoes in the databaseServer class are there only for me to test it. I am implementing the classes in an index.php file as follows:

```
<?php

include('definitions.php');
include('class_lib.php');

$bmazed = new databaseServer();

$bmazed->connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

$sql = "INSERT INTO blah
VALUES ('testing 92')";

$bmazed->query($sql);

$bmazed->disconnect();

// $control = new userControl();

// $uname = "Test1";
// $pword = "test1";

// $control->createUser($uname,$pword);

echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";

?>
```

Lines have been commented out for testing purposes, so I don't have to keep re-writing code.

I really have no idea where the problem lies, I've checked syntax and everything seems fine.

Comment: I've tried all the suggested answers, but none of them seem to get the script to work. I have edited the original question to show more of my code. As mentioned, the code is purely for testing purposes so has a few weird things in there like seemingly random echoes.

Comment: @Saladin run `php -l lib_class.php` and you will see that it complains about unexpected `{` and `else` in the `if` block where you do the `INSERT`. That's because you are missing a closing `)` on that `if` block. When developing code make sure you have `error_reporting` and `display_errors` enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize `$server` in the constructor:

```
class userControl {

 private $server;

 function __construct() {
  $this->server = new databaseServer();
 }

 function createUser($uname,$pword) {
  $this->server->connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
  $result = $this->server->query("SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE uname='" . $this->server->real_escape_string($uname) . "'");
  if ($this->result->num_rows() === 0) {

   if ($this->server->query("INSERT INTO user_list (uname, pword) VALUES ( '" . $this->server->real_escape_string($uname) . "','" . $this->server->real_escape_string($pword) . "')") {
    echo "User added Succesfully";
    }
   else {
    echo "Error Adding User";
    }

  else {
   echo "User already exists";
   }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot assign class or instance properties that depend on runtime information when you declare the classes. See the [chapter on Class Properties in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Change the class to read:

```
class userControl
{
    protected $_server;

    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->_server = new databaseServer();
    }
}
```

Also, to access class/instance members, you have to to use the `$this` keyword, e.g.

```
$this->_server->connect();
```

On a sidenote, while [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) is fine, [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) is better. It helps your code staying maintainable and loosely coupled, which means it will be much easier to replace components, for instance when writing [UnitTests](http://www.phpunit.de/). So consider changing the constructor to use [Dependency Injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection).

Comment: Or even better would be to use dependency injection to put the database server into the class `public funciton __construct(DatabaseServer $server) { $this->_server = $server; }`

Comment: I disagree with your use of underscores as variable prefixes, given that your example is clearly PHP5 code.

Comment: @Alan I am using [ZF's coding standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798916/why-does-the-zend-framework-prepend-an-underscore-here/1799034#1799034) but feel free to disagree with this convention. On a sidenote, [PEAR's coding conventions require the underscore for private properties, but no longer for protected properties when using PHP5.](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php)

Comment: @ircmaxell: good call.  DI is definitely the right thing to do here.

Answer (score 1):

For one, $server won't be accessible from within createUser() because it's in a different scope. PHP scope works a bit differently than one would expect from a C-style language.

Try either passing the $server to createUser(), or initializing the server in createUser(), in which case you should probably have a getServer() function so that you're not initializing it needlessly.

The third option is by far the worst, which is doing "global $server" at the top, inside the function. But it's very bad practice. You have been warned.

Last but not least, you should probably look for COUNT(*) than * in the SQL query, because otherwise you're selecting all the users. :)

If you want further information on PHP's scope, see here (highly recommended):
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The syntactical stuff certainly was a problem. But even more fundamentally wrong with my code was the fact that the databaseServer->query method doesn't return a value. Making it return a value fixed the problem.

I think, sometimes, it's not possible to see the wood for the trees. :)